# Using suffixes without std::literals

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14

I recently read that the literal suffices like `s`, `h`, `ms` etc in C++14 have been put in the namespace `std::literals`. So if I'm to use them then I should either include the namespace or use `std::literals::` to denote those suffixes. However when I tried the following program ([cpp.sh/9ytu](http://cpp.sh/9ytu)) without using any of the above I got the required output :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    auto str = "He is there"s;
    auto timegap = 1s;
    cout << "The string is :-" << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(timegap);
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
/*Output:-
The string is :-
He is there
*/
```

As you can see I haven't included any `namespace` or `std::literals::` still my program runs correctly. I tried this in *Orwell DevC++*, *C++ Shell*, *Coliru* & got the same output everywhere. What's the issue ?

Comment: you do have `using namespace std;`, and literals reside in an inline namespace inside `std`, don't they?

Comment: Always tag "c++" as well, otherwise e.g. syntax highlighting is disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`literals` and `chrono_literals` are inline namespaces - see [[time.syn]](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.syn) in this particular case:

```
inline namespace literals {
inline namespace chrono_literals {
    // 20.12.5.8, suffixes for duration literals
    constexpr chrono::hours h(unsigned long long);
    […]
```

Therefore, due to `using namespace std;`, all UDLs are found.

Comment: then wats the use of putting them in other namespaces instead of `std` alone

Comment: @AnkitAcharya So you can write `using namespace std::literals;` if you don't want to outpour the entire namespace `std`.